# JPA Id property and Relationship property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have worked a bit with Entity in ASP.NET MVC and a model class would look something like this

```
public class Address()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

Where the stateId property and reference to the State object are both stored. However I never see this in JPA code / example.

In JPA it would look like the following:

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "addressSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "addressSeq", sequenceName = "T_ADDRESS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_1")
    private String streetLine1;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_2")
    private String streetLine2;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
    private String postalCode;

    // Mapping Properties
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private State state;

    ....
}
```

Would there be any benefit to also storing the actual StateID in the JPA entity as such?

```
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "addressSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "addressSeq", sequenceName = "T_ADDRESS_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_1")
    private String streetLine1;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "STREET_LINE_2")
    private String streetLine2;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    // I'm new!!!!
    @Column(name = "STATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long stateId;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "POSTAL_CODE")
    private String postalCode;

    // Mapping Properties
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private State state;

}
```

I would think either stateId or state would have to be marked as not insertable and not updatable otherwise Hibernate would try to do both.

Is there any benefit to showing the stateId if there is already a referenced State object? Is this common in JPA?

Off my head I thought the main benefit would be you could still view the Ids without necessarily fetching the associated object.

Comment: I don't see any value in having such a field. If you want, you can add a getter `getStateId` that returns `state.getId()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not required.
You can simply get it by calling getter, as mentioned by Tunaki in comment.

Actually hibernate maintains graph between objects.

So before persisting, you simple do...

address.setState() and state.setAddress();

Answer (score 0):

With JPA, there is almost no point in mapping both the id and the entity with that id. You can do that (provided that you map one of them as readonly), but there are no real benefits of doing this in terms of optimization. In fact, if you map state as **eager**, it is always fetched from DB **together with `Address`** regardless if you access id by stateId or by state.getId().

If you want to retrieve the stateId **without retrieving whole State entity** from the database, you can just map state with **lazy loading**, like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private State state;
```

In that case, only a proxy object will be created instead of real State object. This object will hold only id of the state, and additional data would be retrieved only when additional data is requred.

If you then issue `address,getState().getId()`, you will get the state Id **without fetching** full data for state object.